# How to aggregate observations based on occurrence within 7 days of each other?

Tags: r, date, dataframe, lubridate, data-cleaning

I have a df that adheres to tidy data principles where each row represents a single observation. Each participant is represented by the variable id and may have 1 or more observations. For each observation there is a date.

```
obs <- 1:10
id <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5)
date <-  as.Date(c("2009-08-26", "2009-08-29", "2011-02-02", "2010-02-16", "2011-01-12", "2008-09-10", "2009-12-17", "2009-12-13", "2009-12-09", "2009-12-03))
mydf <- cbind.data.frame(obs, id, date)
```

I would like to be able to aggregate the dataframe so that for every individual id, observations that happen within 7 days of eachother are grouped as a single observation.

In the example code above, this would mean that individual id = 1 would not have two observations, he would have 1 (as 2009-08-26 and 2009-08-29 are within 7 days of eachother). I would also like to avoid 'chaining' as could happen with individual id = 5 above, were obs = 10 and obs = 9 are within 7 days of eachother, and obs = 9 and obs = 8 are within 7 days of eachother, but obs = 10 and obs = 8 are not within 7 days of eachother and should not be grouped.

Any ideas?